# helm-ag (or similar) find in javascript files only

Tags: helm, search, helm-for-files

I'd like to restrict find/grep to (say) only javascript files (mainly because that's what i do in "another editor").

Javascript files in my legacy Ruby-on-Rails project have one of these file extensions:-

*.js, .js.erb, .coffee, .js.coffee, .js.coffee.erb, .jsx, .js.jsx, .js.jsx.erb* (and maybe more)

If i could, i would restrict find to files with these file extensions, and pre-define this list so i don't have to type it each time.

I think i need to write a custom function, if there is a way to specify filetype, but I'm struggling to discover how to do this.. and maybe I've just picked up a weird workflow from my old editor?

EDIT: sorry the question wasn't clear.. i don't want to fix it so that emacs always searches in Javascript files.. when i want to search in Javascript files, i want to search only files with those extensions.. when i want to search in html files i want to only search in files with extensions .html, .html.erb, .html.haml, .haml, etc.

Answer (score 11):

If you use `helm-ag` command, you can specify option like `-G\.js$ search_pattern`, or if you use `helm-do-ag`, you can use `C-u` prefix for specifying extension.

This is screencast.

[image]

Thanks for using `helm-ag`.

Comment: How can we specify to search in .js and in .java files only?  (that is, 2 different file extensions)

Comment: I never understood the names `helm-ag` and `helm-do-ag`. What do they really mean?  How to recall what they do?

Answer (score 1):

## If using `ag`

If you are using `ag`, you can place an `.agignore` file in the project root with the files you would want to ignore. Here's an example:

```
# Extension ignores
*.log
*~
*#*#
*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [helm-ag-use-grep-ignore-list](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag#helm-ag-use-grep-ignore-listdefault-nil) and specify ignore patterns in `grep-find-ignored-files` and `grep-find-ignored-director`.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have in mind a list of file types you want to search notice that the usual argument to `find` which selects files is `-name` which takes a globbing pattern. So something like `-name *.ns.*` should match all the Javascript files in your project.

*Helm* and it's *ag* integration probably have something similar.

These commands record history. Use <kbd>C-p</kbd> or the up arrow to bring back previous `grep-find` searches. You can use <kbd>C-r .ns.</kbd> to recall the last search you did across Javascript files, then simply edit the search pattern.